# Are blog statistics public information?

Tags: discussion, statistics, blog-overflow

Moderators are banned from posting information about the site statistics in a public location, but what about blog stats? Is it okay to discuss anything about the stats, and if so, where would one draw the line?

Comment: Blog stats are in a completely separate location, accessible only through the blog, as far as I know. I imagine the line would be right there -- either it's information related to the blog or to the SE site. There isn't much room for ambiguity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blog stats should be treated the same way we treat site stats:

Don't show the actual numbers, but feel free to discuss the trends with your users.

"We had a big spike on April 10th from such-and-such post"  <--- Good

"On April 10th we had 12,234 page views which is a huge increase our average of 3,147."  <--- Bad

"On April 10th we saw about a four-fold increase on our average traffic from such-and-such post"  <--- Good

Comment: Why can't the exact numbers be public information?